# How can I create multiple click events for the same element

Tags: javascript

Say I want to do this:

```
document.onclick = () => {
    if (target && target.matches('[data-toggle-modal]')) {
        showModal();
    }
}
```

And then in another JS file:

```
document.onclick = () => {
    console.log('test');
}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Never use `onclick`, or any of the other `onX` event properties, mostly for this reason; ie. you can't assign multiple events. Use `addEventListener()` instead

Comment: `document.onclick` is deprecated use `addEventListener`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Thank you - I have learned something new!